# Single Page Application Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, asp.net-spa

My company is re-writing its e-commerce site as a single page application using the new Web API / SPA features in MVC 4. We're not sure about the best way how to handle authentication.

Specific questions:

1. How do we handle both encrypted and non-encrypted communication? Clearly, we need to use HTTPS for the login, account, and checkout AJAX, but we'd like to use HTTP for browsing the catalog in order to avoid expensive SSL handshakes that would slow the whole site down. Is this even possible for a SPA, or are we stuck with HTTPS for everything?
2. What sort of authentication should we use? Primarily our site will be accessed from a web browser, so cookies may be fine. But down the road, we may want to make a custom iPhone app. Is Basic Authentication, OpenId, or OAUTH preferable? If so, why?

   1. If we go with Forms Auth and cookies, will the [redirect issue](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) be fixed for the release of MVC 4, or do I have to use the haack?
   2. If we go with Basic Authentication, how do you do persistent sessions, so that users don't have to log in every time they go to the page again.
   3. Which authentication methods are well supported by ASP.NET MVC 4. It'd be ideal not to have to write a lot of specialized code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why, for the love of $DEITY, would you build an ecommerce site as an SPA ?

Comment: 'cause it's a really good idea if done well!

Comment: What did you finally used for this app?

Comment: We ended up going all SSL and using Basic Auth.

Answer (score 10):

### 1. How do we handle both encrypted and non-encrypted communication? Are we stuck with one protocol, https, with a spa?

You are not stuck with one protocol. With a spa you can use ajax to communicate over http or https, whichever one you choose at any given time.  I would use https for anytime your are sending sensitive information like a persons name or their birthdate or login credentials.

Once a user logins to your site over https then your server can set a forms authentication cookie for that user. This cookie should be an encrypted value that ties their session to the server.  You must be aware that if the rest of your site is using http then you have the risk of this cookie being passed over the wire in plain text.  Even though the contents of the cookie can be encrypted, using an encryption algorithm of your choosing, a malicious person can steal this cookie and jack your user's session.

This might not be a big deal to you though if they are only allowed to browse the site and create a shopping cart.  Once the user is ready to checkout then you should re-authenticate the user, over https, as a sort of double check to make sure they are not a malicious user.  Amazon does this.

### 2. What sort of authentication should we use?

Well, that's all a matter of what features do you want your site to have.

**OAuth** is for exposing webservices which you can allow other sites to call with delegated access.  What this means is that if you have a user who wants another site (site x) to be able to access features on your site for their profile.  The site x can redirect the user to an oauth endpoint on your site which will authenticate the user.  Your oauth endpoint will ask the user if its okay that certain features are shared with site x and if the user agrees a token will be generated. The user passes this token to site x where site x will make server to server calls to your site.  Site x will present the token in the calls so the calls to your services will be a delegated access call.  OAuth is a way of provisioning other sites to make delegated access to your services. I hope i was able to explain that clearly.. I'm not always good at this.

**OpenID** is not a very secure way of handling authentication its more of a convenience so that users don't have to be hassled with registering an account with your site.  Because OpenID is completely open you are trusting another provider to validate your users.  If the third party provider's user store is compromised then your users are compromised also.  It's an example of a voucher system where you are basically saying I will trust who you say you are, if you can have an OpenID provider vouch for you.

Another solution is **WS-Federation**.  WS-Federation is if you have multiple sites and you want to have 1 authentication provider that you trust.  This authentication provider can be yours and basically all your sites say if you want access to my site then you have to first be authenticated with my authentication provider.  This authentication provider can live on a seperate domain and can choose any authentication mechanism it chooses. You are trusting that this auth provider will do its best job to manage your users accounts.

WS-Federation can be overkill though if you only want authentication on your site and don't have multiple sites.  In that case I would just recommend doing **Forms Authentication** and this should be simple enough to do. There are lots of examples of how to do this and microsoft provides many solutions for how to do this. You should look into creating a custom membership provider.

---

Once a user has been authenticated with your site you should create a [forms authentication cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443). This cookie ties the user to their session on the server.  This applies to all the scenarios listed above. MVC 4 supports all the scenarios listed above also.

Thanks, and feel free to ask more questions if I wasn't clear enough.

** EDIT 12/1/2017 **
Coming back to this question years later I have learned that relying on cookies for REST based APIs is not a good idea. You don't want to create a session on your web application because it makes your app harder to scale. So, if you need authentication then use HTTPS with some form of authentication (BASIC, DIGEST, Token Based, etc..).  So, your SPA client appl will set the Authorization header on every http request and then your web server app will re-authenticate every request.

Answer (score 0):

The main downside of using ASP.NET's form based security is that it assumes you're want a 401 web page when your authentication fails (useless when you're doing an AJAX call) and it's really designed around doing redirects which kind breaks the whole SPA pattern.  You can hack around it but it's not designed for the purpose you're using it.

This toolkit may provide an alternative to ASP.NET'as form model.
Not yet sure how mature it is ...

http://www.fluentsecurity.net

Feedback welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I just started working with webapi myself so don't consider my answer authorative. I'm not a security expert though I should be. I ran into the same questions as you did and found, as you did, that there *is* no authorative answer though - within mvc webapi at any rate. Looking at other webapi specs may give you some inspiration.

The simplest way I came across was of course using SSL. That let's you get away with sending credentials in clear text in the header. Doesn't break rest.

My api will employ SSL all the way but I wanted to double up anyway. So I'm sending an encrypted key in the querystring for all my requests. Pretty much the way cookieless authentication works for a non api asp site, but mvc doesn't play with it so I've rolled my own solution.

On a mobile site, the user would log in, be redirected, to the app with the encrypted key encoded into the js. So he'll initially have a cookiebased auth for the site, and be responsible for it's protection, password saving etc.

Another api consumer would get a more permanent "secret" from a dev site yet to be made and use that to check out a key.

Normally mvc authentication is stateless, meaning the ticket is never invalidated server side. If you controll the client you can just ignore invalidate cookie requests if the server logs you out, and just keep on reusing the ticket. Eventuelly you might want to keep track of your tickets server side, but it's not stateless, doubt if it's restfull, and by consequence scalability taket a hit. But authentication is pretty important so...